# Is the Wii RVL-101 compatible with the Active Life mat controller?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii

Is there a Active Life game mat controller that works with the Wii RVL-101 console? I can't find the hidden panel.

Comment: I'm guessing this question is getting downvotes because it looks a lot like a recommendation topic, but the question seems to be more about outdated peripheral. It should be fine as a question of wether or not an updated version was ever released with later version of the game, or even on its own.

Comment: @DJPirtu That's still a shopping recommendation.  More narrow, but still asking us to find something that meets specific criteria.

Comment: @Frank I disagree. I do not see this question any different than a question asking, for example "Is there a port of *Game X* to *System Y*" At least if we rule out 3rd party peripherals.

Comment: @Frank I agree with Pirtu. It asks for compatibility, not if he should buy it. This is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness At no point did I say *anything* about whether he's supposed to buy it or not.  This is strictly, "I want product X that does criteria Y".  That's a shopping rec, through and through, and categorically off-topic.

Comment: @Frank Then this is a shopping rec too, but it was never even attempted to be closed: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41119/is-it-safe-to-buy-a-pre-owned-wii You are seeing things too strict again. Or this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64788/what-wii-consoles-can-play-gamecube-games